# Unicode symbol not showing up in Android - Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I am trying use unicode symbol in one of the pages in my app, currently facing a issue where the symbol doesnt show up in mobile / andorid - chrome browser it shows empty box instead (No glyph found symbol). Works perfectly in desktop - chrome browser. (Added screenshots below).

I am trying to use "WIDE-HEADED RIGHTWARDS BARB ARROW" U+1F86A ""

Unicode Symbol References:

http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html

https://unicode-table.com/en/1F86A/

As it is one of the common symbols supported in majority of the fonts , ideal expectation is it should render and show the arrow correctly.

Desktop View

[image: desktop view - character is readable]

Mobile View

[image: mobile view - character is unreadable]

I have re-created the issue in this codepen, any suggestions would be really helpful.

https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/WNOdvre

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>
      Resources
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Unicode just links code point (number) to a character name. it has nothing to do on how to display characters. This is a task of fonts (and shaping engines). So check that the font you are using contains such character (note: because technical limitation, no single font can handle more then few scripts)

Comment: It's not showing up using iOS 14, either.

Comment: ...nor using macOS 11.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `➔` ([U+2794, Heavy Wide-Headed Rightwards Arrow](https://unicode-table.com/en/2794/)) instead. It's more widely supported.

Alternatively, try using an emoji: ➡️